# Add comma in all rows of a column in DF except last row in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which contains a column 'Account'. I want to add ',' in the end of each row in the column 'Account' except the last column. My desired output looks something like this:

```
AccountId    AccountId
123456       123456,
436358       436358,
747379       747379,
654697       654697,
649470       649470
```

In the output the comma is not added in the last row. The code which I have written applies comma in all the row including the last one. My code look like this:

```
temp = pd.read_csv('E:\2021-01-31.csv' , usecols=['AccountId'])
temp['AccountId'] = temp['AccountId'].apply(lambda x: "{:},".format(x))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the format to a slice of the dataframe

```
temp['AccountId'][:-1] = temp['AccountId'][:-1].apply(lambda x: "{:},".format(x))
print(temp['AccountId'])
```

Output

```
0    123456,
1    436358,
2    747379,
3    654697,
4     649470
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['AccountId'] = df['AccountId'].apply(lambda x: x+',')
```